# How can I add rows of data with dynamic images in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I want to add specific images to a datagrid row, depending on the data displayed on that row. These images need to be functional buttons with click handlers and everything.

For example, if a row displays status of a certain element, like "Editable" then the image displayed in the cell next to it needs to be a green flag, if it isn't Editable then I red flag should appear.

Comment: What version of Flex generally speaking you just need to create an item renderer which is a visual implementation that you tell the grid to use, also are you using an advanced data grid or the normal data grid?  http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/20/formatting-a-flex-datagrid-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer/

Comment: Adding some sample code and showing us what you've already tried would probably help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need images and click handlers, there is an option to embed icons inside a datagrid.

Also, for a datagrid ,clicking on any row triggers the click event,the handler to which will give you datagrid.selectedIndex as the index of the row you clicked, which you can then use to get the data in that specific row and according to the data do a specific action you need.

To render icons in datagrid, you might want to check for labelFunction attribute, which allows you to specify a function , each time data in a datagrid row is filled, which yuo can use to determine the icon you would need the datagrid to render and show to the user.